# Collapsing Toolbar in ViewPager Fragment won't show option menu

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, optionmenu

**Hello,**

I have an activity  with ViewPager in its layout. The ViewPager has 5 Fragments. The Fragments has a CollapsingToolbar with an image and a custom ListView (impementing NestedScrollChild). Now i want to show an option menu on Toolbar, but i can't get it to work. The menu isn't showing.

While searching for a solution (also here) i found out, that it is possible to inflate the menu in one of three codepositions:

1: in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the Fragment

2: in the View `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the Fragment

3: in the `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the Fragmnent

I have tried all of them, but the result is allways the same --> no option menu shown. I have placed a `Log` in `the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` but the logcat never show the message, so the function was never reached.

*Can somebody help me to find the right answer how to show the option menu?*

Here the sources:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="de.example.test.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/part_navigation_toplevel"
        android:id="@+id/pMain_INC_Toplevel" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pMain_VP_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pMain_INC_Toplevel"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_list.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="de.example.test.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/pFragmentList_CC"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/pFragmentList_ABL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:background="@drawable/draw_bg_standard_element"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/pFragmentList_CTB">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/img_theme_blank"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <de.example.test.pakMainFragments.NestedScrollingListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="de.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/pFragmentList_LV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5.0sp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_normal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**menu_main_feed.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_reload"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_reload"
        android:title="Reload"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_length"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="timeperiode"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_showrelationships"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="show relationships"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_showcomments"
        android:orderInCategory="400"
        android:title="show comments"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />
</menu>
```

**ListFragment.java (in parts):**

```
package de.example.test.pakMainFragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import de.example.test.R;


public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    // tested posibility 1:
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list,container, false);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pFragmentList_CTB);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getString(R.string.sTitleFeed));

        NestedScrollingListView lvList = (NestedScrollingListView) v.findViewById(R.id.pFragmentList_LV);

        /* removed for better reading */

        // tested posibility 2: in onCreate()
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main_feed, menu);
        Log.e("ListFragment", "onCreateOptionsMenu");
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }

    // tested posibility 3:
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public static ListFragment newInstance(String sText) {

        FeedFragment fList = new ListFragment();
        Bundle bList = new Bundle();
        bList.putString("msg", sText);
        fList.setArguments(bList);
        return fList;
    }
}
```

*Thank you!*

**EDIT**

i use a style without ActionBar. Now i try a style with actionBar and i can see the option menu in the ActionBar of the MainActivity, but i want it in the Collapsing Toolbar of the Fragment... How i can solve this problem?

**style.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Style for Toolbar in Fragment is overwrítten in Fragment layout xml

Comment: have you tried with `openOptionsMenu();`?

Comment: Sorry,  can you post your style or selected theme i had this problem caused by wrong style

Comment: i edited my post. the option menu is on the hided ActionBar. I need it on the Toolbar in fragment layout.

Comment: So add toolbar outside of the collapsing toolbar and set layout behaviour like your nestedscroll view

Comment: but i need my toolbar under my toplevel-navigation layout. so my viewpager sourrounds my content and the toolbar ist content.

Comment: At all i had a lot of problems with viewpager in collapsing layout, i also tried custom viewpager, custom listview and even custom nestedscrollview but endedup with no success, but i hope you get success,

Comment: i solved all problems so far and all works fine. But the option menu will not place at the right bar. ok, in worst case i can add different toolbar_layout files including the different menus in hardcoded style but i am searching for a cleaner way. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Justl24 same issue here, do you have a workaround?